# Multicollinearity in mixed log-linear model

Tags: mixed-model, interpretation, multicollinearity, scales, log-linear

I am currently running a mixed log-linear model which is in this form:

Log yit = Xit + X2it + (1|individu)

I suspect a multicollinearity ( cor (Xit , X2it) close to 1 ). Do you think it makes sense to scale the explanatory variables (Xit). Or is there another alternative? If yes, how may I interpret the result( 1 SD?).

I already tried to linearize (Log yit = log Xit + (log Xit )2 + (1|individu)) but the result is not better.
Thanks

Comment: with such a high correlation you could either omit one of them or orthogonalize through PCA.

Comment: Thank you @utobi, I and come back to you

Comment: for orthogonalization it is important to use standardized covariates with the mean removed and variance scaled to 1.

Comment: No, standardization it’s not relevant and  it won’t solve the collinearity either.

Comment: but it is required before the orthogonalization, isn't it?

Comment: No, not necessarily.